# Using Christian theological texts for a Torah class

Tags: halacha, christianity

1. Would there be a problem with quoting a Christian theologian’s words (e.g., C.S. Lewis) while teaching in order to advance an idea? (I might want to do this if he speaks particularly well on a certain point.)
2. If it’s okay to quote the words of a Christian theologian, would there be a problem with telling the class that it was written by a Christian theologian?

Comment: As to #2, I would certainly say that as a piece of full disclosure.

Comment: The Sonico Press' Hertz (former Chief Rabbi of Great Britain) version of the Pentateuch was the classic Chumash used in many Othodox synagogues for much of the mid 20th century and even to this day, at least in New York City. The bibliography includes many non-Jewish sources and references. So, I would assume Gabi, that the answer is "yes" Christian theologian's texts could be used. My further gusess is that not extclusively.

Comment: Related: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1573/using-christian-interpretations-in-answers

Comment: Re: Charles Koppleman's point-- The Rambam seems to take the opposite position: in the introduction to the Eight Chapters, he says he's going to refrain from 'mentioning the names of the authorities drawn upon' because some readers might not be open to teachings if they are said in the name of certain (presumably Greek or Muslim) authorities.

Answer (score 2):

Gabi, there are so many things related to religion in general that there is much crossover where texts by authors of different faiths can serve several purposes. Sometimes someone just makes the point really well. At other times using such materials might help spread toleration by showing where similarities lie between different religions. Finally, extrapolating from @Charles Koppelman above, mentioning where the material comes from would be important and would protect the necessary barriers between different faiths, as you don't want someone going around saying, "some great rabbi said..." and being mistaken. Disinformation is never too helpful.